# System function in Swift Xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, swift, system, jailbreak

I'm trying to do an app for respring and reboot my jailbroken device by clicking a button. I know that the reboot command is simply "reboot" and the respring command is "killall backboardd" but in Swift 4 I can't use the "system" function because of this --> 'system' is unavailable in Swift: Use posix_spawn APIs or NSTask instead.

I tried with this.

```
func system(_ command: String) {
    var args = command.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let path = args.first
    args.remove(at: 0)
    let task = CommandLine()
    task.launchPath = path
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
}

@IBAction func respringAction(_ sender: Any) {
    system("killall backboardd");
}
```

but give me this error --> 'CommandLine' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers.

What can I do?

Comment: I think you're shadowing an existing `system` function

Comment: @Alexander nope, i tried to rename the function but this is not the problem, the problem is in `let task = CommandLine()` but i don't understand why

Comment: Where does `CommandLine` come from?

Comment: I don't think so. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/commandline

Comment: if i use `Process` i get this --> Use of unresolved identifier 'Process'; did you mean 'Progress'?

Comment: Did you `import Foundation`?

Comment: Yes i already imported

Comment: Is `NSTask` or `Task` available?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `Task` was the name of `Process` pre Swift 4 (IIRC), and `NSTask` was its ObjC counterpart. Do those work in your code?

Comment: can you contact me in private?

Comment: I'd rather not, tbh :p

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: This was tested and works on my Mac, but I don't have any jailbroken iOS devices, and so have no way to test there.**

Here it is, all cleaned up:

```
func system(_ command: String) {
    let argsArray = command.split(separator: " ").map { (substr) -> String in
        return String(substr)
    }
    guard argsArray.count != 0 else { return  }

    let command = strdup(argsArray.first!)
    let args = argsArray.map { strdup($0) } + [nil]
    posix_spawn(nil, command, nil, nil, args, nil)
    return
}

system("/bin/echo you are cool man")
system("/bin/ls -l /")
```

I don't have jailbroken iPhone but I know this works on my Mac.
Using this will require you know the full pathname to the command you want to run, like ***/bin/ls*** in the example above.

If you want to be able to pass a command line that's interpreted by the shell, which you might, use this alternate version:

```
func shellInterpretedSystem(_ command: String) {
    let argsArray = [
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        command
        ].map { (substr) -> String in
            return String(substr)
    }
    guard argsArray.count != 0 else { return  }

    let command = strdup(argsArray.first!)
    let args = argsArray.map { strdup($0) } + [nil]
    posix_spawn(nil, command, nil, nil, args, nil)
    return
}

shellInterpretedSystem("ls -l /Users")
```

In this case, your PATH variable etc will be taken into account, and things like asterisks (*) will be expanded.

Comment: ... how to jailbreak my phone to test?

Comment: unc0ver (you must be on 12.0-12.1.2) btw it doesn't work:(

Comment: ty.  Did the solution above fork for you?  If so, please mark as accepted.  If not, pls let me know.

Comment: the "btw it doesn't work:(" was for the solution you wrote:( the unc0ver jb works!"

Comment: What happens when you run?  ... and what are you using for the command to run?

Comment: i'm trying to run `killall backboardd` but nothing happens.

Comment: are you able to run while connected to debugger ?

Comment: Use the shellInterpretedSystem instead of the system one

Comment: i used also the shellInterpretedSystem but do the same thing of the system one. (i tested on iPhone X JB) :(